# How do I caluclate which capacitor to use as a filter after the brdige rectifier using the 18Vpk A.C. 50 Hz as a source?

Tags: power-supply, capacitor, bridge-rectifier, ripple

Like how would I go about on it? From calcualating the ripple voltage, to knowing which value of farads to use.

Comment: What did your research show you and where are you stuck? There are many tutorials on the web. You need to take more care with your typing. "5OHz" is not the same as "50Hz".

Comment: Ah sorry , The O and 0 were very close to each other on my keyboard. The research shows me the the ripple factor and the calacuation to get the Vr(rms) and Vm and such

Comment: So what's the question then?

Comment: The question was how to calcualate the value of the filter/smoothing capactior and what infomation do I need to calcualate it? The half time period? the voltage? the current?

Comment: Start with your specifications. (1) What voltage do you need, (2) what ripple voltage can you tolerate, (3) what is your maximum load current and (4) what is your mains frequency (which will give you the half-cycle period)? Plug those into the calculator and it will tell you the capacitance required.

Comment: _"value of farads"_ This physical quantity is called _capacitance_.

Comment: Full bridge or half bridge? And it depends on the load current obviously. Most likely all you need for approximation is Q=IT=CU.

Comment: Mains Frequency = 50Hz. Can tolerate about 0.3V ripple voltage, maximum loaded current is 1, And I need the voltage to be 18Volts, and this is a bridge rectifer I'm using

Answer (score 0):

Q = C * V

which after calculus, and constant dC/dT, and a bit of algebra, becomes

I = C * dV/dT.

Making the 4 variables be "1" provides an equality.

You can substitute different values, for any 3, and compute the 4rth.